# Beginner Android Studio Concern Regarding TextView and Strings

Tags: java, android

Basically, I am trying to create an application which finds the factors of a number, but I'm not entirely sure what to do in order to display all the factors, as right now it only displays the last one.

```
while(factorNumber <= finalValue){ 
  if(finalValue % factorNumber == 0){
    tv2.setText(factorNumber + " is a factor of " + finalValue);
  } 
  factorNumber ++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Accumulate the string before calling `setText`:

```
try (Formatter fmt = new Formatter()) {
  while(factorNumber <= finalValue){ 
    if(finalValue % factorNumber == 0){
      fmt.format("%s is a factor of %s%n", factorNumber, finalValue);
    } 
    factorNumber ++;
  }
  tv2.setText(fmt.toString());
}
```

---

Note that you don't need to test as many factors: you can stop once `finalValue > sqrt(finalValue)`; or:

```
while (factorNumber * factorNumber <= finalValue) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can append to text view or simply create a list of factors and display it.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

while(factorNumber <= finalValue){ 
   if(finalValue % factorNumber == 0){
         list.add(factorNumber);
   } 
   factorNumber ++;
}

tv2.setText(factorNumber + " is a factor of " + list);
```

Don't forget to import :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

Comment: I think you mean to add `factorNumber` to the list, rather than `finalValue` repeatedly.

Comment: Oh yes..it is my mistake. Editing my answer.@AndyTurner

Answer (score 0):

Try using append

```
boolean isFirstTime = true;
while(factorNumber <= finalValue){ 
  if(finalValue % factorNumber == 0){
    if(isFirstTime)
    {
      tv2.append(factorNumber);
      isFirstTime = false;
    }else{
      tv2.append(","+factorNumber);
    }
  } 
  factorNumber ++;
}
tv2.append(" is a factor of " + finalValue + "\n");
```